# “Ctrl + click to follow link” in VSCode terminal to open a Windows File Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I use VSCode as home tool for a couple of things and run python programs just on the VSCode terminal.
If I write in the Terminal "https://stackoverflow.com/questions" I can ctrl+click to Follow Link in the Browser, which of course save a lot of time.
I want to be able to open the Windows File Explorer for a directory writing something like "C:\Temp" or open the default associated application (Notepad) writing something like "C:\Temp\fileexample.txt"

I would be pleased if somebody could tell me if this is posible.
Thanks in advance.

P.S.: English is not my mother tongue; please excuse any errors.